# What is the right position of literals in String Comparison?

Tags: java, pmd

I have

```
if (localName.equals("TaxName")) {
```

but PMD says

```
Position literals first in String comparisons
```

Comment: Well, if PMD complains about literals being on the right, I don't think you have much other choices than putting them on the left (aka  [yoda condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2430307#2430307) style) :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`"TaxName".equals(localName)` is better as if `localName` is null you won't get a null pointer exception.

Comment: That is only better if you want to allow for that. Personally, I can't remember such a situation where that wasn't an error in my code that I wanted to catch as soon as possible.

Comment: regex to replace those: 
`([a-zA-Z][^ ]+)\.equals\(("[^"]*")\)`
Replace with: `\2.equals(\1)`

Answer (score 8):

PMD should also be telling you *why* it generates this warning. From [the rules documentation](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/rules/design.html#PositionLiteralsFirstInComparisons) on the PMD website:

> Position literals first in String comparisons - that way if the String is null you won't get a NullPointerException, it'll just return false.

Comment: In some cases, if a variable is null, code should regard it as unequal to a string.  In other cases, it indicates a problem and the more quickly the problem is flagged, the better.  In the latter situation, `variable.equals("literal")` is better, since it will trap if variable is null.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer to position literals first, i.e. :

```
if ("TaxName".equals(localName)) { ...
```

This way you do a right comparison for the case of null, instead of getting NullPointerException.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, that doesn't make sense to me.  If the code catches a NullPointerException, then it's done work that you won't have to do later.  If localName ends up being null, and that causes a problem later on, then it'll be harder to trace.  Don't change code to make the compiler happy.  If your code throws a NullPointerException, then it's saved you debugging time later.

Comment: I totally disagree and definitely prefer to write `CONSTANT.equals(variable)` rather than doing a preliminary `null` check.

Comment: If localName is null and you try to use it later on you'll get exactly the same effect as the original code, i.e an NPE. But, more significantly, one should always make the compiler happy - it knows what its doing. I would even recommend going into the compiler settings for your IDE of choice and upgrade all those compiler warnings into errors.

Comment: @CurtainDog upgrading compiler warnings into errors would effectively stall my company's productivity for a year. I'm sure 90% of the people on SO would agree. I'm not saying you're not right in principle, because those warnings turn into bugs all too often, I'm just saying in it's easier said than done.

Comment: @PascalThivent: If `null` would be a legitimate value for the variable which should be regarded as not equal to the string, testing the literal for equality with the variable is easier than manually testing the variable for null and then comparing to the string.  If, however, null is *not* a legitimate value for the variable, saying `variable.Equals("Literal")` will effectively provide an `Assert(variable != null)` for free.

Answer (score -1):

To avoid that warning, a simpler solution is check nullpointers before, wich is recommended in every object we manage, not only in this very case:

```
if (localName!=null && localName.equals("TaxName")) {
    ...
}
```